# Postgres SQL column aliasing based on a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find a way to do SQL column aliasing based on a query. I'm well aware that the SQL below is not valid, it's just provided as an example of what I wish did worked. Can anyone think of a way of doing this?

```
select col_001_name AS (select col_001_name FROM public.intparms WHERE base_tbl_name = '130')
FROM public.intparms WHERE base_tbl_name = '130';
```

Comment: If you want a dynamic column alias, then you need dynamic SQL. What are you trying to achieve? Sample data and desired result would help clarifying your question.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a parameters table and alias columns values by the parameter name value in the column.  You could get this to work with dynamic sql, with difficulty if you  want a single column, and lots of difficulty with multiple columns, esp if you don't know the parameter names ahead of time. You would be much better off just select the parameter name and its value.